# JavaScript not working when Partial View is called

Tags: javascript, partial-views

Good day,

When loading partial view, the JavaScript functionality is not working for the code that was loaded. When I put it back to the index, everything works like a charm. I tried a lot of solutions and non of them worked or I did not quite understood, so I decided to ask.

I have a modal (in my index), where I'm loading the partial view on button click. Everything works as intented but the JS for the partial view is not working. I know I'm missing something, but I cant figure out what.

Function on how I am calling the partial view:

```
$("#coinflipCreateBtn").click(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/coinflip/load-inventory",
    success: function (d) {
        debugger;
        $('#coinflip-inventory-userId').html(d);
    },
    error: function (exception) {
        alert("Exception:" + exception);
    }
});
});
```

And the function that suppose to work on the partial view:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('col-item');

$(x).on('click', function () {
    var assetId = $(this).data('assetid');

    $(this).toggleClass('selected');

    checkValueIfExist(assetsArray, assetId);
    buttonVisibility();
});
```

Should I call it differently? include JS somehow in the partial or? Any help is appreciated...

Cheers

Comment: because you bind the events before they exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that binds the events to elements is executed before you load in new HTML. You collect all elements by classname, and then bind them to a click event. Clearly any HTML that does not exist yet cannot be part of the collection of elements, and thus there are no click events registered to them.

You could refactor the code where you bind  the events to a function that you call after the `$.html(d)` part. After running that code again, things should work as you would like them to.